# How to Convert .i file to .asm with cl.exe

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, compiler-errors, cl

I have a simple C code like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){   
printf ("this a test");       
return 0;}
```

I want convert this code (code.c) to code.i (Preprocessing file) ,so convert code.i to assembly file *.*
for convert code.c to code.i , I use `cl /P code.c` and get `code.i` file.
but when convert `code.i` to assembly file whit this command , I have error :
`cl /Fa code.asm code.i`

error :

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.20.27508.1 for x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'code.as', object file assumed
> cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'code.i', object file assumed
> Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.20.27508.1
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:code.exe
>
> code.asm
>
> code.i
>
> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'code.asm'

How to convert a .i file to assembly file with cl.exe?

If I use `cl /Fa code.i`:

> cl /Fa code.i Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version
> 19.20.27508.1 for x86 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type
> 'code.i', object file assumed Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version
> 14.20.27508.1 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:code.exe code.i code.i : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt
> file: cannot read at 0x321AD

Comment: You command uses `code.asm` as a source file. What happens if you just leave out that name?

Comment: And I don't think [the `/Fa` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fa-fa-listing-file?view=msvc-170) is the right choice to create an actual assembly file, that can be later used to create an object file.

Comment: I use cl /Fa code.i or cl /Fa code.i code.asm , but I get error

Comment: Do you get the *same* error with `cl /Fa code.i`?  The error you show in the question seems pretty obvious: It's a compiler, so you can use it like `cl foo.cc bar.cc` to compile+link multiple input files; it treats all its non-option args as input filenames.  (There's probably an option like  `-o` to specify an output filename.)

Comment: I think `cl /c /Facode.asm /Tccode.i` should work (note: there are no spaces before the file names). It will also produce an object file. If you omit `/c` it will additionally create an object and executable.